# ManyToManyField with model_to_dict(self)

Tags: django, dictionary, django-models

Not sure if the title is the correct one, sorry for the inconvenience.

I'm having a problem on sending a ManyToManyField from a model to a dictionary using the model_to_dict() Below is my code

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import model_to_dict

from app_1.models import *

class Stuff(models.Model):
   thing_1 = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
   thing_2 = models.ManyToManyField(OtherStuff, blank=True, related_name="thing")

   def toJSON(self):
      item = model_to_dict(self)
      item['thing'] = self.thing.toJSON()
      return item
```

When I run a query and load my Stuff model, I get the following error:

```
from app_2.models import *
s = Stuff.objects.get(pk=1)

# here is where I send my model to a dictionary
s.toJSON()
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
   File "P:\test\app\app_2\stuff\models.py", line 10, in toJSON
      return item
AttributeError: 'ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'toJSON'
```

I've come across multiple ways of sending a ManyToManyField to a dictionary, however, none of them use the model_to_dict(). I'd like to use this method due to it's simplicity of usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this approach, you'll need to use this syntax:

```
item['thing'] = [t.toJSON() for t in self.thing_2.all()]
```

And also, implement the `toJSON` method for the `OtherStuff` model.

Or you can use `model_to_dict` for `OtherStuff` as well:

```
   def toJSON(self):
      item = model_to_dict(self)
      item['thing'] = [model_to_dict(t) for t in self.thing_2.all()]
      return item
```